# How to apply a function to every element in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

This is probably a very basic question but I can't find the answer in other questions. I have two lists that I have used to create a 2D dataframe, let's say:

```py
X= np.arange(0, 2.01, 0.25)
Y= np.arange(10, 30, 5.0) 

df = pd.DataFrame(index = X, columns = Y)
print(df)
```

Which gives:

```py
     10.0 15.0 20.0 25.0
0.00  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
0.25  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
0.50  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
0.75  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1.00  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1.25  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1.50  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1.75  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2.00  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I would like to go through all elements in the dataframe and use the values of `X` and `Y` as inputs to some function, `foo`, that I have written. For example, in the 2rd row, 1st column (using zero indexing) position I have `(X, Y) = (0.5, 15.0)`, so in this position I would like to apply `foo(0.5, 15.0)` and not `foo(2, 1)`.

I think I should be able to use `df.apply()` or `df.applymap()` somehow but I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your problem requires access to both the index and column labels of your `df` you probably want `df.apply()`.

`df.apply()` has access to a `pandas.Series` representing each row/column (dependent on `axis` argument value) and you will have access to the column name and index; whereas `df.applymap()` utilises each individual value of `df` at runtime - so you wouldn't necessarily have access to the index and column name as required.

**Example**

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

def foo(name, index):
    return name - index

x = np.arange(0, 2.01, 0.25)
y = np.arange(10, 30, 5.0) 

df = pd.DataFrame(index = x, columns = y)

df.apply(lambda x: foo(x.name, x.index))
```

**Output**

```
       10.0   15.0   20.0   25.0
0.00  10.00  15.00  20.00  25.00
0.25   9.75  14.75  19.75  24.75
0.50   9.50  14.50  19.50  24.50
0.75   9.25  14.25  19.25  24.25
1.00   9.00  14.00  19.00  24.00
1.25   8.75  13.75  18.75  23.75
1.50   8.50  13.50  18.50  23.50
1.75   8.25  13.25  18.25  23.25
2.00   8.00  13.00  18.00  23.00
```

In the above example the column name and index of each Series constituting `df` is passed to `foo()` by way of `df.apply()`. Within `foo()` each value is defined by subtracting it's own index value from it's own column name value. Here you can see that the index value for each row is accessed using `x.index` and the column value is accessed using `x.name` within the call within `df.apply()`.

**Update**

Many thanks to @SyntaxError for pointing out that `x.index` and `x.name` could be passed to `foo()` within `df.apply()` instead of feeding the entire Series (`x`) into the function and accessing the values manually therein. As mentioned, this seems to fit OP's use case in a much neater manner than my original response - which was largely the same but passed each `x` series into `foo()` which then had responsibility for extracting `x.name` and `x.column`.

Comment: great answer!

to make this possible with a arbitrary `foo` function which takes 2 values you could use 
`df.apply(lambda x: foo(x.name, x.index))`

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful answer JPI93 and then SyntaxError you pre-empted my follow up question

Comment: @SyntaxError Brilliant point, thanks so much for pointing this out :)  I've updated my answer to reflect this as it is so much cleaner; more widely applicable, translatable etc.

Comment: @JPI93 I am sure your code works; but when I copied it to colab it returns `NaN`s, I can't understand why...

Answer (score 2):

that would be my approach:

```
from itertools import product

def foo(row, col):
    return row * col

for row, col in product(df.index, df.columns):
    df.loc[row, col] = foo(row, col)
```

output:

```
      10.0   15.0 20.0   25.0
0.00     0      0    0      0
0.25   2.5   3.75    5   6.25
0.50     5    7.5   10   12.5
0.75   7.5  11.25   15  18.75
1.00    10     15   20     25
1.25  12.5  18.75   25  31.25
1.50    15   22.5   30   37.5
1.75  17.5  26.25   35  43.75
2.00    20     30   40     50
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    X= np.arange(0, 2.01, 0.25)
    Y= np.arange(10, 30, 5.0) 

    df = pd.DataFrame(index = X, columns = Y)

    # example of function
    def foo(x, y):
        return x*y

    # apply the fonction to each element of the data frame getting the raw and the column name as parameters
    for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df.shape[1]):
        df.iloc[i,j] = foo (float(df.columns[j]),float(df.index[i]))
```